# Fivestar appears on content type, but can't vote

Tags: rating

I have problem with Fivestars module, (Drupal7).

It is configured in field and appears on content type page, but cannot vote
(like voting is disabled - when inspecting with firebug, i see no Javascript activity over stars, and no any possible javascript conflict.)

Permissions are set correctly.

What in the world could cause this ? 
(it seems more-less like plug-and-play module :D )

Answer (score 1):

When adding the FiveStar field,

- If you choose "Rated while viewing" , that means all users can rate the node (with permissions) can rate the node. This is ideal to allow users to rate how well the article was writtem etc).
- If you choose "rated while editing", it will make the rating field disabled (static field) for other users than the node author. This is ideal for review nodes to allow the reviewer to leave their ratings while making the node or any other entity.

Comment: I know, and i have rate while viewing, but one is not able to vote. I checked the module on vanilla, and it worked. When i filled my database with content types etc, it stopped working. It is some kind of conflict but i have no clue

Comment: check for the permissions that is if a user is granted the permission to vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked the `permission` and chose "`rated while viewing`" correctly you must check the "`Allow users to vote on their own content.`" option in the edit section of your field as well. it lets you vote for your own content.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable "users can vote for their own materials" (sorry, if translation is somewhat inaccurate).

That would be in /admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/fields/field_vote

My fivestar field is called "vote", thus "field_vote" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Allow voting on the entity" is enabled in the Field: Rating displays field within the View.